# Small query regarding the format of WDDatePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, date-format, wddatepicker

I am using this [WebDelicious DatePicker](http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins-demo/wdDatePicker/sample.htm) for my application. I want to get the format of the date in `YYYY-MM-DD`, but I have no clue how to give the format. I tried to meddle around with the JS but I don't think it is worth.

Currently the initialization code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[name=password]').passStrengthify();
        $('input[name=dob]').datepicker({
            picker: '<span class="picker"></span>'
        });
    });
</script>
```

I tried giving this, but it didn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[name=password]').passStrengthify();
        $('input[name=dob]').datepicker({
            picker: '<span class="picker"></span>',
            dateFormat: 'YYYY/MM/DD'
        });
    });
</script>
```

There's also not much documentation available either in the site or in the source. Can someone throw a light on how am I supposed to change the format of the returning value in the datepicker? Thanks.

---

**Steps to reproduce.**

Since this cannot be given in a fiddle, or can be hosted anywhere, to reproduce the results, please do the following:

1. Download [WebDelicious DatePicker](http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins-demo/wdDatePicker.zip).
2. Open the file `sample.htm` that comes with the archive.
3. Click on the datepicker image and select a date.
4. It inputs in `m/d/Y` format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've been looking abit at `i18n.datepicker.dateformat.fulldayvalue` I think this could be what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into wdDatePicker/src/Plugins/datepicker_lang_US.js copy paste/replace

```
 "fulldayvalue": "yyyy/MM/dd",
            "separator": "/",
            "year_index": 0,
            "month_index": 1,
            "day_index": 2,
```

Comment: Lemme check this and say.

Answer (score 1):

Change in **datepicker_lang_US.js** file

line #4 n 5
**Before**
            "fulldayvalue": "M/d/yyyy",
            "separator": "/",

**After**
            "fulldayvalue": "MM-dd-yyyy",
            "separator": "-",

Comment: Lemme check this and say.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do .

```
$( "#datePicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
$( "#datePicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat" );
```